# Can we use longtable and sidetable same time?

Tags: tables, longtable

I have a 14x14 matrix and it does not fit on a page either way. Is there a way to use sidetable and longtable together? or is there anyway to fit this table into the latex?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    
  
\title{stackoverflow}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
    
\footnotesize
\begin{sidewaystable}
\sidewaystablefn%
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\textheight}
\caption{\label{AICbsX} Number of equally spaced knots used in the model and the corresponding AIC values. The row and column labels are the number of knots for $x$ and $y$, respectively.}

\begin{tabular*}{\textheight}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|cllllllllllllll|@{\extracolsep{\fill}}}
\toprule%
\hline
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 \\ 
  \hline
1 & 312716.25 & 312619.87 & 312551.82 & 312227.96 & 312342.06 & 312190.00 & 312211.67 & 312216.59 & 312101.91 & 312128.26 & 312132.05 & 311847.92 & 311952.28 & 311939.22 \\ 
  2 & 312663.58 & 312567.22 & 312496.59 & 312163.85 & 312280.10 & 312125.40 & 312148.26 & 312153.51 & 312038.15 & 312064.47 & 312068.05 & 311783.50 & 311889.59 & 311872.41 \\ 
  3 & 311937.32 & 311841.10 & 311721.09 & 311216.72 & 311384.77 & 311147.57 & 311187.63 & 311173.25 & 311069.23 & 311113.56 & 311098.54 & 310849.01 & 310934.94 & 310939.82 \\ 
  4 & 312184.49 & 312088.22 & 311953.58 & 311524.14 & 311671.47 & 311464.00 & 311504.91 & 311490.27 & 311373.65 & 311416.15 & 311406.17 & 311121.41 & 311217.90 & 311208.56 \\ 
  5 & 311337.59 & 311241.79 & 311107.75 & 310560.32 & 310736.55 & 310476.38 & 310534.88 & 310495.25 & 310398.80 & 310459.22 & 310427.15 & 310211.53 & 310276.23 & 310303.13 \\ 
  6 & 311452.23 & 311356.57 & 311215.40 & 310690.52 & 310864.42 & 310606.87 & 310662.91 & 310619.99 & 310518.93 & 310578.44 & 310543.62 & 310309.38 & 310371.75 & 310405.96 \\ 
  7 & 311141.94 & 311046.32 & 310900.06 & 310339.46 & 310510.77 & 310264.07 & 310318.44 & 310280.11 & 310196.93 & 310250.91 & 310214.51 & 310030.79 & 310077.66 & 310114.67 \\ 
  8 & 311243.41 & 311147.87 & 311010.43 & 310450.27 & 310628.69 & 310366.75 & 310421.64 & 310381.69 & 310292.80 & 310348.86 & 310315.93 & 310118.04 & 310170.38 & 310207.50 \\ 
  9 & 311041.48 & 310945.87 & 310793.05 & 310229.40 & 310396.59 & 310163.10 & 310211.47 & 310179.78 & 310100.25 & 310148.15 & 310116.42 & 309943.71 & 309972.91 & 310024.48 \\ 
  10 & 311094.33 & 310998.65 & 310853.37 & 310291.15 & 310461.53 & 310224.00 & 310268.52 & 310240.77 & 310160.25 & 310207.12 & 310180.26 & 310003.34 & 310041.08 & 310086.26 \\ 
  11 & 310999.87 & 310904.31 & 310749.32 & 310183.52 & 310349.50 & 310117.84 & 310167.02 & 310133.81 & 310055.39 & 310102.52 & 310068.78 & 309901.11 & 309922.12 & 309979.58 \\ 
  12 & 310980.82 & 310885.08 & 310725.37 & 310178.04 & 310336.01 & 310125.32 & 310161.64 & 310144.09 & 310068.97 & 310108.43 & 310086.24 & 309923.83 & 309953.04 & 310000.85 \\ 
  13 & 310960.47 & 310864.79 & 310707.75 & 310137.56 & 310303.36 & 310070.98 & 310121.61 & 310085.21 & 310007.66 & 310055.51 & 310017.67 & 309855.94 & 309870.14 & 309932.13 \\ 
  14 & 310906.03 & 310810.32 & 310643.57 & 310085.73 & 310242.25 & 310033.32 & 310072.88 & 310050.75 & 309979.24 & 310018.59 & 309991.31 & 309841.11 & 309862.92 & 309914.90 \\ 
   \hline
\botrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}\end{sidewaystable}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The table is very wide but has only 14 rows and you have plenty of space at the left- and right-hand side. You could split it in two column groups and append remaining columns underneath.

Comment: Thanks. That's actually the last solution I am thinking of. I can do 2 tables as 14x7 if I cannot get a better solution.

Comment: your original question is answered with `\begin{landscape}\begin{longtable}...` using `lscape` and `longtable` packages.